# Tag a Build in TeamCity from another Build

Tags: teamcity

We have a Build that compiles and creates an artifact.  Then we have another Build that uses the last Compile build and Deploys it to the proper environment.  Once that is complete, I have to go and Tag the build in TC that it was pushed to the environment.  Is there a way that I can tag the Compile Build that is was deployed using the Deploy Build?

Comment: What version of TeanCity are you using

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an easy way to do this (i.e. through a TeamCity configuration setting) but you probably could accomplish this using the [REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin) from your build script.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TeamCity 6 or above because you have a build dependency chain from the Deployment Build to the Main Build either through artifact dependencies, snapshot dependencies or both you can just tag your Deployment Build. This is because the UI will show you a tree view of the dependencies that the deployment used and you can navigate to the actual build.

One thing you can do, and in my opinion should do, is to tag your source control from TeamCity if you are using a source control that supports tagging/labelling. You should probably set your Deployment Build up with a snapshot dependency as well as the artifact dependency, especially if your build files are in the same repository. On your Main Build you should get TeamCity to label your repository on a successful build with something like "build-1.2.3.4". Then on your Deployment Build you should get it to label the repository after a successful build with "deployed-1.2.3.4". If you deploy to different environments then you can get it to label the repository accordingly.